# Delete sql rows where IDs are in another table and need to match a certain field in that table

Tags: sql

In database `JoePizza`, I have 2 tables one similar to this (`Inventory`) table 1

```
ItemNum  Name Dept_ID price
---------------------------
101      Test  27     8.99
105      Tree  35     6.99
108      Save  68     2.99
```

Table #2 has columns like this (`Printers`)

```
ItemNum  Print  Action   Budget
----------------------------------
101       Yes   All      10.99
105       NO    None      5.99
108       Yes   None     17.99
```

What I want to do is delete the rows in Table 2 that say match the same ITEM for DEPT (45).

Which would in turn remove Row 105 from table 2.

I am not sure how to compare and get the information from one table to change a second table.

I can get information from either table but not sure how to do what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: What's wrong with `delete from table2 where deviceid in (select deviceid from table1 where dept = 45)` ? That's a generic solution. More performant ones exist for specific databases. Please name your database.

Comment: Database name is JoePizza and tables are Inventory and table 2 is Printers

Comment: This is my modified query based on your suggestion and my tables ... delete from Printers where ItemNum in (select ItemNum from Inventory where Dept_ID = 35) I ran that query and I got this reply ... Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'NONE' to data type int.

Comment: I believe I fixed the issue I had with your query I added a ' ' around the dept = '45' and that seemed to work well ... thank you for your help I really appreciate it this was driving me nuts for a few hrs I was not sure how to compare the 2 tables to get the results I was looking for ... Thank you again